# Windows 10 Cannot extend partition: "There is not enough space available on the disks(s) to complete the operation"

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

The disk in question used to contain a Fedora installation and GRUB, which the latest windows update seems to have rendered inert. I have deleted the old partition that Fedora was installed on, but Windows does not seem to want to extend my bulk storage partition over the now unallocated space. In fact, it appears that I cannot touch the unallocated space at all, since even attempting to create a new partition under windows returns "The size of the extent is less than the minimum."

Answer (score 0):

I find windows Disk manager to be problematic. Unless there really is an issue you haven't noticed, you should use *Gparted*. It can be used in any Linux system or in a live version.

link to live version: https://gparted.org/download.php

Command for installing on Linux: `sudo apt install gparted`